# Modelling file import using Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I am developing an app that will process a user-prepared text file, and I'm trying to use BDD with Cucumber.

Obviously I could produce a pile of sample files and write scenarios like:

```
When I import file_1
Then I see [some data on the screen]
```

and so on, but those sample files (do they count as test fixtures?) look ugly and even if I give them more meaningful names don't really convey the substance of the scenarios.

Is there a clearer, more expressive solution to handling file input with Cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to use a scenario outline.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

```
  Scenario Outline: file importing
  When I import <file>
  Then I see <data>

  Examples:
    | file    | data     |
    |  file1  |  data1   |
    |  file2  |  data2   |
```

Comment: That doesn't really do anything for the clarity and expressiveness, does it? The person that sees the specification can't tell what it is about the file that leads to the particular response (particularly why the file might be rejected).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concentrating on how this is being done (importing a file), concentrate on using the feature to say why this is being done. So why is your user providing this data, and what are they trying to achieve by asking you to process it.

Generally the mechanism of an operation appearing in a feature is a smell e.g.

```
Smelly
  When I fill in my password with '123456'
  And I fill in my username with 'frank'

Fragrant
  When I sign in
```

Comment: So something like:

    `When I load a valid file`

and

    `When I load an invalid file`


Pushing all the ways a file can be invalid into RSpec examples? Ok for the happy path, but how do I specify failure responses? I still end up with stuff like:

    `When I load a file that contains an invalid user name in row 3`
    `Then I get an error message 'Invalid user name in row 3'`

Yuk! But how else do I specify that the error message (correctly) shows the row in which the error occurred? It's certainly something I need to test, because it's ripe for off-by-one errors.

Comment: Thats still about how you are doing things, not why, so there isn't enough context yet to understand the problem. What I can say is that for scenarios with Cucumber you should not be doing exhuastive testing. This means you would test very few sad paths, perhaps only one, and you would just test that you see an error (not specify what the error is). If you want to do more exhuastive tests, then you should write unit tests for the class/method that does the file processing.

Comment: The situation is that we will periodically be sent bulk data that is needed for the application to perform its task, so it needs to be uploaded to the application.

Comment: So expand on that, talk about who is sending the data and why, and who is recieving the data, and what they expect to happen. Then you'll have some context. At the integration layer you just want to show that if something goes wrong you get an error message. You deal with detail like 'off-by-one-errors' in unit tests.